# Making an NSTimer's interval shorter and shorter

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nstimer

I'm a newbie when it comes to Objective-C so please make your answers as easy as posible.

Here is the m-file for a Pong-game made in Xcode 4.5. In the method viewDidLoad is a timer. My problem is to change the interval (now float gap = 0.05) so the ball goes faster and faster.. I guess I have to make a new timer somewhere else and not have the repeat set to YES. But i have no idea where to put it and what to do with the float gap.

Hope you understand what i mean.

PongOne.m:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    paddle.center = CGPointMake(location.x, paddle.center.y);
}
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
-(void)CPU {
    ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x + xgain, ball.center.y + ygain);
    if (ball.center.x < 15)
        xgain = abs(xgain);

    if (ball.center.y < 15)
        ygain = abs(ygain);
        gap = gap + 0.01;

    if (ball.center.x > 305)
        xgain = -abs(xgain);

    if (ball.center.y > 445){
        score++;
        if (score <= 2){
            ball.center = CGPointMake(100, 100);
            label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", score];
        } else {
            [timer invalidate];
            timer = nil;
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"byta1" sender:self];
        }
    }
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, paddle.frame))
        ygain = -abs(ygain);
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, paddle2.frame))
        ygain = abs(ygain);
    paddle2.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x, paddle2.center.y);
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:gap target: self selector:@selector(CPU)         userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    xgain = 10;
    ygain = 10;
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried doing what you say you think you need to do?

Comment: You mean adding a new timer somewhere else?

Comment: Do you really want the timer itself to speed up? Surely you want to increase the speed of the ball. You can do that without changing your timer cycle. For example, multiply xgain and ygain by some varying factor.

Comment: Or use a static counter plus modulus value and an `if` statement to only fire the timer on certain iterations `if(count % modVal == 0) //do stuff`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just remove your current timer using `[timer invalidate]` when you want to change it and make a new one like you do in your `viewDidLoad`. Or, make it not repeat, then in `CPU` create a new one every frame with whatever the current interval should be. Regardless, I wouldn't recommend `NSTimer` for any kind of run loop. Also, I'd say it's a bad idea to alter the timing of your whole run loop just to change the speed of one object. Rather, you should alter how much you move it each frame instead. Why not change `{x,y}Gain` themselves?

Comment: @user2059738 Great! When you can, click the checkmark on the left to accept this answers so others know it has been solved.